# Maintaining lua/c++ variables through through multiple script calls

Tags: c++, variables, lua

I'm pretty new to lua scripting, but want to incorporate scripting into my game engine.  Currently I have lua linked up to c++ in a basic manner where I can call methods from c++ classes and vise-versa. Lua scripts are setup as components and you can essentially attach scripts to a game object. However, I'm having an issue where my variables are being reset each time a script is called.  Here is a basic example of a script:

```
--lua script--
input = InputManager()

function initalize()

end

function update()
    if(input:KeyDown(KEY_SPACE)) then
        print("Random before: ", input.random)
        input.random = input.random + 10
        print("Random after: ", input.random)
    end
end
```

Initialize is called when the script component is attached and update is called every frame.  In this example, in my c++ InputManager class that I bind up to lua, I have a integer random that is initialized to 5.  I'm using lunafive properties to control the getting and setting of variables.

When I hit space i expect the first iteration to print out:

Random before: 5

Random after: 15

And then the next iteration:

Random before: 15

Random after: 25

However, every iteration I get that first result of 5 and 15. I realize this is because I'm loading the script each update method so it is probably just creating a new instance of InputManager.

How do I go about creating an instance of an object (i.e InputManager) and maintain that same instance every time I call update.

That way I could do something like this:

```
 input = nil

    function initalize()
       input = InputManager()
    end

    function update()
       print(input.random)
    end
```

and not have an undefined instance of input once update is called.  Hopefully this all makes sense, if not I can clarify! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I was actually able to solve this right after I posted this haha.  It turns out that instead of calling luaL_dofile each time I load the script, I use luaL_dofile on initialization and then luaL_loadfile on later methods such as update.  Please feel free to continue to answer the question as I feel there may be better methods out there and I would love to learn them!